# meaning of 'had' in "had a student pull out a gun"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from [a webpage](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/teachers-on-school-shootings-none-of-us-are-built-for-this-/6625156.html):

> Salfia has a closer connection to gun threats than most. Her mother,
> also a West Virginia teacher, **had** a student pull out a gun in her
> classroom seven years ago. After talking to the student for two hours,
> she helped bring the incident to a peaceful end.

Does 'had' in bold mean 'to cause or command to do something'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the causative sense, but not quite the same.

The idiom is "Have (something happen) (to her)" and it means "be affected by something happening" - [sense 19 of Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have#Verb).